# Android PDF app that shows up on "choose an action" file upload

Tags: android, pdf

A website with a file upload button and Android/Chome. If I click an upload button, a menu is presented that gives me the choice of uploading directly from the camera, similar to this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZn50.png)

Apparently, only apps categorized as camera apps are permitted to be shown here. Here is my top question.

1) Does anyone know of a PDF app that will let you click the file upload button and take a picture that is *directly uploaded to a website as a PDF* by taking a picture with the camera?

2) If there isn't one, is there a PDF app that a created PDF shows up in the recent files options, like android does for the last photo you took...or the last screen capture?

YES, I know you can go through documents and browse to a PDF to upload. We are looking for a streamlined version for dummies, where someone can PDF a receipt and upload it as a PDF in just a few clicks, vs saving it and wading through menus trying to attach it. Basically a camera that saves as PDF and shows up on the "choose an action" menu would be fantastic. Failing that, I have yet to install a PDF creator on Android that shows up in my recent files...you know, like everything else does. I always have to go through documents and browse a few folders deep to find the PDF with every app I have installed.

And I can't google this, because apparently Android's "choose an action" menu is one of the least known menus in the universe. And I find this odd...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an `Intent` filter to the `Manifest.xml`, to whatever `Activity`, which shall be available to handle PDF files ... eg. this one handles PDF originating from the local file-system, because it has `android:scheme="file"` defined.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

and there are already apps alike

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piksoft.turboscan

Comment: @Jeremy that's how to register Intent actions for that "choose an action" menu ...

Comment: Just googling, it seems something that the app developer should add to the Manifest.xml. That's going to be hard for me to do when I don't have access to everyone's phones. I downloaded the above app and, while it works fine, it doesn't show up in the "choose an action" and the PDFs it creates do not show up in the recent files. I have to go to documents and browser through folders looking for the created PDF.  But you did give me more terms to actually google for. Thanks!

Comment: @user1544428 when it's one and the same application, it can have it's PDF in it's own directory... which one can scan for files, as shown in below answer. there is no need to browse much.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you are creating the PDF's yourself. It sounds like you could create your own directory in the phones memory for only "pdfs" that is recorded from you all. Then create a custom listview that pulls in the files from that folder, based on time. You could probably even use a simple BottomSheetDialog to have that similar "Share to" action.

You can list files in a directory by using the .listFiles method

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/pdfs";
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

Would create a PDF pojo object, and build your object list in this loop :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm yet to find a PDF app that shows up with an "intent" or "choose an action." However, I did find something close and it doesn't require an app at all. Take picture with camera. Open photos and simply choose to print the image. Choose print to PDF.

Go to website and start a file upload. When "when choose an action" shows up, go to files. Now the PDF is in "recent files" and the PDF that you just created is at the top of the list. No trying to navigate through folders to find PDFs created by some app (that never show up in the recent files...at least I'm yet to find one. And installing a bunch of PDF apps trying to find one that does isn't that appealing to me).

Only a few more clicks than just uploading directly from the camera.

Only issue I see is that PDFs created like this are a bit bigger than I would like, but oh well. It's a big step in the right direction.